# Spring boot controllers not mapped for url

Tags: spring-boot

I have spring controllers in my app, when executing my app the all controllers end URLs are showing `not fond(404)` error in browser.

```
public class EmployeeContoller {
 private EmployeeService employeeService; @Autowired.  
 public EmployeeContoller (EmployeeService employeeService)
 {this.employeeService=employeeService.   @RequestMapping("/employee/{id}")
 public Employee getEmployee(@PathVariable String id){ return employeeService.getEmployee(I'd);
}
```

Comment: Provide your URL mapping configuration and the URL you are trying to hit.

Comment: Please edit your question itself, do not post code in comment, it is not readable.

Comment: You should annotate your EmployeeContoller class with RestController Controller annotation to let Spring know that it should be auto registered
https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/